# Detect mouse wheel -END- event on NSScrollView (AppKit)

Tags: cocoa, appkit, nsscrollview

I have a feeling it's another Apple's "magic",
but I can't detect very simple and basic event :
when user stop using mouse wheel to scroll (-end- event)

```
- (void)scrollWheel:(NSEvent *)event
{
    [super scrollWheel:event];
    
   
    ////    NSEventPhaseNone        = 0, // event not associated with a phase.
    ////    NSEventPhaseBegan       = 0x1 << 0,
    ////    NSEventPhaseStationary  = 0x1 << 1,
    ////    NSEventPhaseChanged     = 0x1 << 2,
    ////    NSEventPhaseEnded       = 0x1 << 3,
    ////    NSEventPhaseCancelled   = 0x1 << 4,
    ////    NSEventPhaseMayBegin    = 0x1 << 5,
    ///
    ///
    //event.phase -always- 0
    //event.momentumPhase -always- 0
    NSLog(@"event.momentumPhase = %lu, event.phase = %lu", (unsigned long)event.momentumPhase, event.phase);
    
    if(event.phase & NSEventPhaseBegan)
    {
        // never called when user start scrolling with mouse wheel
        NSLog(@"NSEventPhaseBegan");
    }
    if(event.phase & NSEventPhaseEnded)
    {
        // never called when user end scrolling with mouse wheel
        NSLog(@"NSEventPhaseEnded");
    }
    
}
```

I checked all the properties of the NSEvent, but there is no data to check.
Googled to check what others are doing. nothing that really solve this.
some solutions was this, but...this return 0 all the time.

Comment: As far as I know there is no mouse-wheel-end-event, like there is no mouse-stopped-moving-event or user-stopped-typing-event. `NSEvent.phase` is used with gestures.

Comment: But there is "user-stopped-scrolling-event" (when moving the scrollbar with mouse). The problem is if user scroll with the mouse wheel I can't detect it also. so it's useless without it.

Comment: The scrollbar detects a mouse-up event. How should an end-of-scrollwheel event be detected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scroll wheel events that are triggered by a mouse with a traditional scroll wheel are handled discretely. There are no `begin / end` phases. Generally speaking, when `NSEvent.momentumPhase` is 0, then the device generating the scroll wheel event is likely a traditional mouse.

A scroll wheel event generated from a trackpad, Magic Mouse or other device that supports "gestures" uses `NSEvent.momentumPhase` to report which phase the scrolling is in. For these events, you can track when scrolling starts and when scrolling ends using `NSEvent.momentumPhase`.

A view can, optionally, post its own `begin / end` notifications that are relevant to how it will handle scrolling, but those notifications are not part of the `NSEvent` mechanism for handling scrolling events.

Depending on your use-case, you might be better off just listening for `NSView.boundsDidChangeNotification` to know when the viewport of your view has changed, rather than trying to override all of the various scrolling triggers.

A lot of this is discussed in Apple's older release notes for AppKit. Sadly, it appears to be just one large document now but if you search around you'll see a few sections discussing how to properly handle scroll wheel events and how they have evolved over the years:

[AppKit Release Notes (macOS 10.12 and Earlier)](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/AppKit/RN-AppKitOlderNotes/index.html)